# Convert an array of array onto Collection Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I have an array of array which results from several sql requests. 
First I make a sql request in a foreach in order to have all the datas i need

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   // Two different Eloquent requests 
   $todo = User::select().....where('users.id' = $id);
   $done = User::select().....where('users.id' = $id);

   // I have operation on Collection that work fine ... 
   $totalTimes = $todo->toBase()->sum('dureeformation') ;
   $spendTimes = $done->toBase()->sum('dureeformation') ;
   $remainingTimes = $totalTimes - $spendTimes;

  $all[] = ['user_id' => $id, 'totalTime' => $totalTimes, 'spendTime' => $spendTimes,'remainingTime' => $remainingTimes ];

}
```

My issue is the following... Outside the foreach i display the values and i have this array of array ...

```
array:16 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "user_id" => 1
    "totalTime" => 465
    "spendTime" => 0
    "remainingTime" => 465
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "user_id" => 3
    "totalTime" => 375
    "spendTime" => 0
    "remainingTime" => 375
  ]
```

I would need to have a Collection instead ... I tried to make $all = Collect(....) but i doesn't give me the expected result.

I need a collection because i have to create a Collection with this created collection and another one from another request.

Concerning this part i already had this case and i can solve it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You said you tried `$all = Collect(....)` why don't you convert the result like `$result  = collect($all)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this helper function :

```
$collection = collect($all);
```

This function will convert your array to collection.

Comment: I tried collect but not this way :) i feel much more better now !